# EntityFramework Save an "frozen image" of the DB at given time

Tags: c#, wpf, database, entity-framework, invoice

I have the following DB structure:

[image: schema]
[fullsize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxCPN.png)

The invoice table is where my trouble is. 
The scenario:
Month 1:
Users buy products, make and attend events and payments. These get saved to the DB.
The last day of the month I want to make a bill/Invoice to every user. This invoice is created and saved. 
Month 2:
The price of every product is changed, the events from month 1 gets changed. Some payments are removed.
When i look up the invoice from Month 1, the data will be different from when i created it, because the values are merely pointers to data in the other tables.

What I want:
To create an unchangeable "image" of the database where changes to the other tables won't affect the invoice. Changes to the invoice has to be made directly.

What I have tried/am trying:

1. Simply making lists of each entity in the Invoice class. Gives foreign key constraint when saving to DB - should I somehow just force it to create a new entity with a new key and a foreign key to the Invoice in the same table?
2. Making subclasses inheriting from super classes and subtables to Payments/Purchases/Products/Eventrelations/Events with a common InvoiceId, creating new entities for each new invoice made.

What is the best solution for me here?

Comment: When you save data for what the user buys you should also store the price they paid at that time - and not look it up via the relationships when you generate your invoice. This goes for any data that may change - do not use relationships to get this data, store a historic snap shot of it.

Comment: What about the payments? If one is deleted, it should still exist in the Invoice.

Comment: That's the point. ...you shouldn't relate historic data to data that can change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your best option is to denormalize the invoice table.

The advantages of normalization is that changes "ripple" through out your model. But you don't want that to happen with your invoice.

So remove the navigation properties to everything you don't want to affect the invoice indirectly and create a field inside the invoice for each value you want to save.

Comment: I think i will create new classes for every existing class. These new classes will only contain fields needed for the invoice.

This will result in lots of duplicate data though - is that not bad?

Comment: Duplicate data is bad if you have to update all of them when you make changes. In your case you don't want to update all so denormalization (duplicate data) makes perfect sense.

I would advice against making a separate set of invoice-product tables (if I understood "new classes" correct). As you'll run into the same problem with updating a product affecting multiple invoices.

If you however want to keep the class structure I suggest you look at storing complex types (referenced classes without a primary key)

Comment: Thanks, that'll work - now on to the implementation :)